# GKE Standard no space left on device

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I ran my cluster on GKE standard mode
all services is find till i found when try to deploy new servicecs

pod status is always "ContainerCreating"

and when describe it got

> Warning  FailedMount  0s    kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp
> failed for volume "kube-api-access-gr995" : write
> /var/lib/kubelet/pods/867eb785-4347-4439-8a22-1be71d8985f5/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-gr995/..2022_07_27_17_22_26.024529456/namespace:
> no space left on device

I already try to delete deployments and redeploy again but not work seen like my master is full of disk but i usage GKE so cann't ssh or do something

Comment: Can you check with node the pod is scheduled on with kubectl get pods -o wide. SSH into that node and run a du -h

Comment: @boredabdel nope i can not exec into pod cause it's not creating yet status is  ContainerCreating

Comment: I didn't no say exec into the pod :)

Use kubectl get pods -o wide to figure out which nodes run the pod. After that SSH into that node and check the filesystem usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no space left on device, which is unexpected. MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume in kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925742/no-space-left-on-device-which-is-unexpected-mountvolume-setup-failed-for-volum)

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre yes it's help i think some config on my deployments is wrong when i create a new one it work fine thanksssss